# Getting Error in Importing json file in Kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

When I am importing the json file containing dashboard and the visualization to Kibana 4  I am getting following error:

```
Saved Objects: Cannot read property 'byName' of undefined
OK
TypeError: Cannot read property 'byName' of undefined
    at FieldAggParamFactory.FieldAggParam.deserialize (http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:84771:53)
    at http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:90104:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at AggConfigFactory.AggConfig.fillDefaults (http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:90082:28)
    at new AggConfig (http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:89996:13)
    at http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:90695:19
    at Array.map (native)
    at new AggConfigs (http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:90693:35)
    at VisFactory.Vis.setState (http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:84236:20)
    at SavedVis._updateVis (http://stciperf:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=9732:92582:17)
```

But importing the same json file for second time works fine and I am able to see my dashboard. Kindly suggests few points.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got the solution ,Check if your index has more than ~5K fields in it? There is a current bug in Kibana 4.x where excessive fields in an index results in this error.

Bug tracking on github is [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1561)